# How to instantiate a class in JNI

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am astonished that this very important detail is missing a comprehensive walkthrough on the internet . Or maybe I am a worst googler . Or a utterly dumb programmer.

I have been working on android since months , however recently I was told to do JNI . My C skills are already rusted . I was however catching up when I stuck on this one and couldn't carry forward .

I want something simple . Here is my native method declaration in my MainActivity

public native Object  createObject();

This is how i intend to use it

```
    Object abc = createObject();
    Integer num = (Integer) abc;
```

I just want to create a java.lang.Integer object from C , and send it to java. It can't get any simpler

```
    jobject Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_callbackJava(JNIEnv * env, jobject this )
{
    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");
    jmethodID methodID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "(I)V");
    jint number = 8 ; 
    return (*env)->NewObject(cls, methodID, number);

}
```

(android ndk r8c)
I get greeted by a stack trace , which crashes my application.

```
12-14 16:10:07.595: D/dalvikvm(302): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libhello-jni.so 0x45f3da60
12-14 16:10:07.625: D/dalvikvm(302): Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libhello-jni.so 0x45f3da60
12-14 16:10:07.625: D/dalvikvm(302): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libhello-jni.so 0x45f3da60, skipping init

12-14 16:10:07.684: W/dalvikvm(302): **JNI WARNING: threadid=1 using env from threadid=0**
12-14 16:10:07.684: W/dalvikvm(302):              in Lcom/example/hellojni/HelloJni;.callbackJava ()V (NewObject)
12-14 16:10:07.684: I/dalvikvm(302): "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
12-14 16:10:07.684: I/dalvikvm(302):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001d8e0 self=0xccb0
12-14 16:10:07.684: I/dalvikvm(302):   | sysTid=302 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345026008
12-14 16:10:07.684: I/dalvikvm(302):   | schedstat=( 152515888 582639885 48 )
12-14 16:10:07.684: I/dalvikvm(302):   at com.example.hellojni.HelloJni.callbackJava(Native Method)
12-14 16:10:07.695: I/dalvikvm(302):   at com.example.hellojni.HelloJni.onCreate(HelloJni.java:59)
12-14 16:10:07.695: I/dalvikvm(302):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-14 16:10:07.695: I/dalvikvm(302):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-14 16:10:07.695: I/dalvikvm(302):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-14 16:10:07.695: I/dalvikvm(302):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-14 16:10:07.695: I/dalvikvm(302):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-14 16:10:07.695: I/dalvikvm(302):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 16:10:07.695: I/dalvikvm(302):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-14 16:10:07.695: I/dalvikvm(302):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-14 16:10:07.695: I/dalvikvm(302):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 16:10:07.695: I/dalvikvm(302):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-14 16:10:07.695: I/dalvikvm(302):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-14 16:10:07.695: I/dalvikvm(302):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-14 16:10:07.695: I/dalvikvm(302):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 16:10:07.704: E/dalvikvm(302): VM aborting
```

Please help me .

Thanks

Comment: Although it does not answer your question, you should use Integer.valueOf().

Comment: @ignis thanks for the comment . And yes I am searching for a way to instantiate a class inside JNI . My motive right now is just to learn that.

Comment: There are plenty of examples around of creating a Java class from JNI, although why you would want to write a JNI method that does that and nothing else escapes me completely.

Answer (score 9):

I was doing a trivial mistake that I found out through some more searching and research over the JNI

i missed putting env in the arguments for NewObject . Here is the correct code in case anyone ever needs it

```
jobject Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_createObject(JNIEnv * env, jobject this )
{

    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");
    jmethodID methodID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "(I)V");
    jobject a=(*env)->NewObject(env,cls, methodID, 5);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: the errors that jni reports are misleading , you can be stuck in them forever , in "limbo"

Comment: To be fair, the VM was expecting a JNIEnv*, and the code was passing in a jclass.  This should have been detected via a compiler warning, although this may not happen with the C bindings because jobject is defined as `void*` (the C++ bindings have a "fake" class hierarchy).  The CheckJNI messages are generally accurate, and are a huge improvement over a simple crash message.